# How do I add onclick to a line of text so that it calls a popup box only when clicked and not on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Thanks to the help of another user, I was able to customize a popup that looks great, but I can't quite get the onclick to work so that the popup isn't displayed until the phone number is clicked. I'd like to show the phone number by itself, and once clicked, a popup will appear which will ask the user, "Call or Text?", then the user clicks on the button of their choice. Thank you!

```
var modal = document.getElementById('textCall');
var span = document.getElementById("close");
modal.style.display = "block";
span.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS

```
.dialogue {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 150px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#close, #closed {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#close:hover,
#close:focus,
#closed:focus,
#closed:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}

#textCall {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<p onclick="textCall">555-5555</p>
<div id="textCall" class="dialogue">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Call or Text?</h2>
        <a href="tel:15555555555">Call</a>
        <a href="sms:15555555555">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkwdwn99/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This function is what you are looking for:

```
function textCall(e) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Check the snippet:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('textCall');
var span = document.getElementById("close");
var number = document.getElementById("number");

number.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('textCall');
var span = document.getElementById("close");

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};

function textCall(e) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.dialogue {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 150px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#number {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#close, #closed {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#close:hover,
#close:focus,
#closed:focus,
#closed:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<p id="number" onclick="textCall()">555-5555</p>
<div id="textCall" class="dialogue">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Call or Text?</h2>
        <a href="tel:15555555555">Call</a>
        <a href="sms:15555555555">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great for the onclick, but it's still loading the popup box on the page load. Is there a way to have the popup box not load until the number is clicked? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @SweetBabyJames I have edited the question to work as you expected now. Try it please.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's kept the popup from executing on page load, but now the popup has disappeared on click.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to initially set `display:'none'` to your modal. You can make `onclick` function for your elements and do `show` or `hide` your modal like this.

**DEMO**

```js
function closeModal(e) {
  document.getElementById('textCall').style.display = "none";
}

function textCall(e) {
  document.getElementById('textCall').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.dialogue {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.number {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#close,
#closed {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#close:hover,
#close:focus,
#closed:focus,
#closed:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 40%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%
}
```

```html
<p class="number" onclick="textCall(this)">555-5555</p>
<div id="textCall" class="dialogue">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span onclick="closeModal(this)" id="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Call or Text?</h2>
    <a href="tel:15555555555">Call</a>
    <a href="sms:15555555555">Text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```